# creating a stack using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, stack

i'm trying to write code for creatin' a stack by usin' an array, for which i'm suppposed to use dynamic memory allocation. The problem is it's not takin' scannin' for the response which determines whether it should exit the loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>

static int top, size, *a, x;

stfull(){
    if(top<size) x = 0;
    else x = 1;
}

stempty(){
    if(!top) x = 1;
    else x = 0;
}

push(int z){
    if(x){
        printf("stack full\tstack overflow\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        a[top] = z;
        top++;
        return;
    }
}

pop(){
    if(x){
        printf("empty stack\tstack underflow\n");
        return;
    }
    else{
        printf("%d  ", a[top]);
        top--;
        return;
    }
}

main(){
    int num, res;
    char ans = 'y';

    printf("array size:\t");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    a = malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    printf("choose number for result\n1. push elements\n2.display elements\n3.exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &res);

    switch(res){
        case 1: 
            while(ans == 'y'){
                printf("enter a number\t");
                scanf("%d", &num);

                push(num);

                printf("enter more?\t");
                ans = getchar();
            }   
        break;
        case 2:
            do{
                pop();

                printf("pop more?\t");
                ans = getchar();
            }while(ans == 'y');
        break;
        case 3: 
            exit(1);
    }
}
```

**sample input**:

**array size**: 5

**choose number for result**

**1. push elements**

**2.display elements**

**3.exit**
1

**enter a number**  3

**enter more?**

the program exits after this point irrespective of the value of ans. Can anyone correct my code?

Comment: `malloc()` is only used to allocate memory at runtime. static variables are initialized at compile time. So you should use `if (!a) a = malloc(size*sizeof(int));`

Comment: creatin', usin', takin', scannin': Anything wrong with the "g" on your keyboard?

Comment: Dont forget that when you ask for a character, the buffer will have a newline character left in it, that will essentially skip over some of your getchar statements.

Comment: Interesting, I've seen this '`void` as implicit-return-type' before (in the [Accent](http://accent.compilertools.net/) parser-generator). But I thought the default implicit return-type was `int`. Was it ever `void` at some point before ANSI-C?

Comment: @Arjun Sreedharan  i tried declarin' *a seperately as int *a, but it made no difference

Comment: your `x` variable looks like a mess, are you using it as a global return value? the horror..

Comment: use scanf("%c",&ans) instead of ans=getchar()

Comment: @Leeor it seems to be used to indicate that the stack is full or empty, but `stfull` and `stempty` are never called...

Comment: @codln That still wouldnt solve the buffer problem he is facing...he will need scanf(" %c",&ans) // notice the space between the percent sign

Comment: @Kninnug `int main()` is implied when using `main()`

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan only for `main`? Because if I compile this with (a recent) GCC it complains about 'return type defaults to `int`' (and then later that the functions don't return anything in a non-`void`-returning function). A quick Google also turns up that `int` is generally the default return type. Yet there is quite some (old) code that appears to assume `void` is the default. For all functions.

Comment: @user3248186 did you change your question after you got solution to old prob?

Comment: @user3248186 i think the better way is to add new questions for new problems. now already given answers have become irrelevant to the current question right

Comment: @user3248186 I rolled back your edit. Please ask a new question. You can always link to this question if you feel they are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code exits because getchar() reads the \n [enter] pressed as the character for ans.
your input is

```
enter a number 3[enter]
```

so

```
ans=getchar();
```

reads [enter]. so one easy solution is use getchar() twice as

```
getchar();
ans=getchar();
```

your code will continue working

Answer (score 0):

you can add this line

```
fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
```

before each getchar when you want to ensure that it doesn't read any previous character. it basically clears the buffer, or more precisely, moves the read point to the end of the buffer.

Comment: The call is portable.
The effect you desire however might not be.

fseek() has too many caveats (in the ISO standard), which when you add in various operating systems, and maybe redirecting stdin from say a file or a pipe, I doubt you'll get what you want in all cases.